# Trying to move files ( in .txt format) containing str 'meta-analysis' from one folder to another-python

Tags: python

```
import shutil
os.chdir('D:\Source')
##i for counting number of files
i=0

for file in os.listdir():
# Trying to move the identified file to a different folder
# but thows PermissionError      

    with open(file,'r',encoding='utf-8')as F:
        for line in F:
            if 'meta-analysis' in line:
                i=i+1
                print(i)
                print(line)
                #attempting to move the relevant file. 
                shutil.move(file,'D:\Research\dest\\'+file )
            else:
                pass
```

Error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file 
>   because it is being used by another process:

Expected behavior:

all the files move to dest folder and moved files are deleted from Source

Comment: Try moving the file after the with block.

Comment: did not work, problem was it then moved the last file.

Comment: Formatted code and put error messages and expected result in separated lines.

Comment: Path separators are not consistent, some are escaped and some not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't move the file with `shutil` while it's still open (inside the `with` clause).  First make a list of files you want to move, then move them.

Comment: Got a list, appended it. now stuck on how to move the list of files. any suggestions.would be appreciated. still learning here. I want to delete the files in the source at the same time.

Comment: `for file in list_of_files_to_move: shutil.move(...)`